# trying to split the file download buffer to into separate threads

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2, http-range

I am trying to download the buffer of file into 5 threads but it seems like it's getting garbled.

```
from numpy import arange
import requests
from threading import Thread
import urllib2

url = 'http://pymotw.com/2/urllib/index.html'
sizeInBytes = r = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers['content-length']

splitBy = 5

splits = arange(splitBy + 1) * (float(sizeInBytes)/splitBy)

dataLst = []

def bufferSplit(url, idx, splits):
    req = urllib2.Request(url,  headers={'Range': 'bytes=%d-%d' % (splits[idx], splits[idx+1])})
    print {'bytes=%d-%d' % (splits[idx], splits[idx+1])}
    dataLst.append(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())


for idx in range(splitBy):
    dlth = Thread(target=bufferSplit, args=(url, idx, splits))
    dlth.start()


print dataLst

with open('page.html', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(''.join(dataLst))
```

**Update:** 
So I worked over and got little but progress, however if I download a jpg it seems to be corrupted;

```
from numpy import arange
import os
import requests
import threading
import urllib2

# url ='http://s1.fans.ge/mp3/201109/08/John_Legend_So_High_Remix(fans_ge).mp3'
url = "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/607800main_kepler1200_1600-1200.jpg"
# url = 'http://pymotw.com/2/urllib/index.html'
sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)


splitBy = 5

dataLst = []


class ThreadedFetch(threading.Thread):
    """ docstring for ThreadedFetch
    """
    def __init__(self, url, fileName, splitBy=5):
        super(ThreadedFetch, self).__init__()
        self.__url = url
        self.__spl = splitBy
        self.__dataLst = []
        self.__fileName = fileName

    def run(self):
        if not sizeInBytes:
            print "Size cannot be determined."
            return
        splits = arange(self.__spl + 1) * (float(sizeInBytes)/self.__spl)
        for idx in range(self.__spl):
            req = urllib2.Request(self.__url,  headers={'Range': 'bytes=%d-%d' % (splits[idx], splits[idx+1])})
            self.__dataLst.append(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())


    def getFileData(self):
        return ''.join(self.__dataLst)


fileName = url.split('/')[-1]

dl = ThreadedFetch(url, fileName)
dl.start()
dl.join()
content = dl.getFileData()
if content:
    with open(fileName, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(content)
    print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName
```

Below is how the image after getting downloaded.

[image: corrupted image]

Comment: There's nothing in your code that guarantees that all the threads have finished after they're started. I would suggest creating a list of `dlth` objects called `dlthreads` and afterwards doing a `for th in dlthreads: th.join()`. Even with that you probably can't assume they'll all finish sequentially in the same order as started, so the `dataLst.append()`s could occur out of order. To fix that you'll need to add something that identifies the buffer number to allow reassembling them in the right order.

Comment: @martineau : I have added updated code, in which i got little bit success, however the downloaded content seems to be corrupt.

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to the way you're downloading the data via multiple requests -- so would concentrate on getting that right before trying to multi-thread the process.

Comment: i got that part right.. will post soon the update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another version of the project.  Differences:

- thread code is a single small function
- each thread downloads a chunk, then stores it in a global threadsafe dictionary
- threads are started, then `join()`ed -- they're all running at once
- when all done, data is reassembled in correct order then written to disk
- extra printing, to verify everything's correct
- output file size is calculated, for an extra comparison

### source

```
import os, requests
import threading
import urllib2
import time

URL = "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/607800main_kepler1200_1600-1200.jpg"

def buildRange(value, numsplits):
    lst = []
    for i in range(numsplits):
        if i == 0:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (i, int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
        else:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0),0)), int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
    return lst

def main(url=None, splitBy=3):
    start_time = time.time()
    if not url:
        print "Please Enter some url to begin download."
        return

    fileName = url.split('/')[-1]
    sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)
    print "%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes
    if not sizeInBytes:
        print "Size cannot be determined."
        return

    dataDict = {}

    # split total num bytes into ranges
    ranges = buildRange(int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)

    def downloadChunk(idx, irange):
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes={}'.format(irange)
        dataDict[idx] = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

    # create one downloading thread per chunk
    downloaders = [
        threading.Thread(
            target=downloadChunk, 
            args=(idx, irange),
        )
        for idx,irange in enumerate(ranges)
        ]

    # start threads, let run in parallel, wait for all to finish
    for th in downloaders:
        th.start()
    for th in downloaders:
        th.join()

    print 'done: got {} chunks, total {} bytes'.format(
        len(dataDict), sum( (
            len(chunk) for chunk in dataDict.values()
        ) )
    )

    print "--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time)

    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        os.remove(fileName)
    # reassemble file in correct order
    with open(fileName, 'w') as fh:
        for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.iteritems()):
            fh.write(chunk)

    print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName
    print 'file size {} bytes'.format(os.path.getsize(fileName))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(URL)
```

### output

```
102331 bytes to download.
done: got 3 chunks, total 102331 bytes
--- 0.380599021912 seconds ---
Finished Writing file 607800main_kepler1200_1600-1200.jpg
file size 102331 bytes
```

Comment: I tried the example, but it seems if we increase the number of splits the time taken is more while it is expected if downloads are going parallel in n number of threads it should finish faster but the opposite is happening...

Comment: there's a good bit of overhead to establishing a TCP, then a HTTP connection.  There won't be any speedup unless the file is pretty big.  A 100KB JPEG probably won't show much difference.

Comment: Apart from that how many maximum connections are possible with server?

Comment: Each connection puts some overhead onto the server, so you don't want to do too many.  I suggest picking a small number like 2-5.

Comment: having used download managers in past, I remember there has always been 6 - 10 max possible splits.

Comment: in theory, you can do many. In practice, you don't want to hog a server's resources. Plus, from the client side you get rapidly diminishing returns.  6 - 10 is probably okay.

Comment: And noone seemingly cared to upvote :) What's wrong with ya all??

Comment: It's all very well and good but this just does not work, we need to change the `head` request to a `get` request with `stream=True` for it to work

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got it working if anyone got any suggestion for possible improvement, you are most welcome.

```
import os
import requests
import threading
import urllib2
import time

url = "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/607800main_kepler1200_1600-1200.jpg"

def buildRange(value, numsplits):
    lst = []
    for i in range(numsplits):
        if i == 0:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (i, int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
        else:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0),0)), int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
    return lst

class SplitBufferThreads(threading.Thread):
    """ Splits the buffer to ny number of threads
        thereby, concurrently downloading through
        ny number of threads.
    """
    def __init__(self, url, byteRange):
        super(SplitBufferThreads, self).__init__()
        self.__url = url
        self.__byteRange = byteRange
        self.req = None

    def run(self):
        self.req = urllib2.Request(self.__url,  headers={'Range': 'bytes=%s' % self.__byteRange})

    def getFileData(self):
        return urllib2.urlopen(self.req).read()


def main(url=None, splitBy=3):
    start_time = time.time()
    if not url:
        print "Please Enter some url to begin download."
        return

    fileName = url.split('/')[-1]
    sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)
    print "%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes
    if not sizeInBytes:
        print "Size cannot be determined."
        return

    dataLst = []
    for idx in range(splitBy):
        byteRange = buildRange(int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)[idx]
        bufTh = SplitBufferThreads(url, byteRange)
        bufTh.start()
        bufTh.join()
        dataLst.append(bufTh.getFileData())

    content = ''.join(dataLst)

    if dataLst:
        if os.path.exists(fileName):
            os.remove(fileName)
        print "--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time)
        with open(fileName, 'w') as fh:
            fh.write(content)
        print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(url)
```

this is the first bare bone code I have got working, I discovered if I set `bufTh` buffer thread to Daemon False then process takes more time to finish.

Comment: What is module `requests`?

Answer (score -1):

I asked ChatGPT to help me with this. I know, I'm cheating :)

Here's the code it produced, and it worked great with a 10GB file that was taking forever to download:

```
import os
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

url = "URL-TO-DOWNLOAD"
num_parts = 10
filename = url.split("/")[-1]
r = requests.head(url)
file_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])

class FilePartDownload:
    def __init__(self, start, end, url, part, progress_bar):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.url = url
        self.part = part
        self.progress_bar = progress_bar

    def download(self):
        # Check if part file already exists
        if os.path.exists(f"{self.part}_{filename}"):
            current_size = os.path.getsize(f"{self.part}_{filename}")
            # Adjust start based on what we already downloaded
            self.start += current_size

        headers = {'Range': f'bytes={self.start}-{self.end}'}
        r = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, stream=True)
        # Open the file in append mode
        with open(f"{self.part}_{filename}", 'ab') as fp:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    fp.write(chunk)
                    self.progress_bar.update(len(chunk))

def combine_files(parts, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
        for part in parts:
            with open(f"{part}_{filename}", 'rb') as fpart:
                fp.write(fpart.read())
            os.remove(f"{part}_{filename}")

parts = list(range(num_parts))
starts = [file_size//num_parts * i for i in range(num_parts)]
ends = [file_size//num_parts * i - 1 for i in range(1, num_parts)] + [file_size]

progress_bar = tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc="Total Progress")

# Create FilePartDownload instances without starting the downloads
downloads = [FilePartDownload(start, end, url, part, progress_bar) for part, start, end in zip(parts, starts, ends)]

# Update the progress bar with the size of already downloaded parts
for download in downloads:
    if os.path.exists(f"{download.part}_{filename}"):
        progress_bar.update(os.path.getsize(f"{download.part}_{filename}"))

# Start the downloads
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for download in downloads:
        executor.submit(download.download)

progress_bar.close()
combine_files(parts, filename)
```